# Text or Bytestring

Tags: string, haskell, text

Good day.

The one thing I now hate about Haskell is quantity of packages for working with string.

First I used native Haskell `[Char]` strings, but when I tried to start using hackage libraries then completely lost in endless conversions. Every package seem to use different strings implementation, some adopts their own handmade thing.

Next I rewrote my code with `Data.Text` strings and `OverloadedStrings` extension, I chose `Text` because it has a wider set of functions, but it seems many projects prefer `ByteString`.
Someone could give short reasoning why to use one or other?

PS: btw how to convert from `Text` to `ByteString`?

> Couldn't match expected type
>   *Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal.ByteString*
>              against inferred type *Text*
>         Expected type: IO Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal.ByteString
>         Inferred type: IO Text

I tried `encodeUtf8` from `Data.Text.Encoding`, but no luck:

> Couldn't match expected type
>   *Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal.ByteString*
>              against inferred type *Data.ByteString.Internal.ByteString*

**UPD:**

Thanks for responses, that *Chunks goodness looks like way to go, but I somewhat shocked with result, my original function looked like this:

```
htmlToItems :: Text -> [Item]
htmlToItems =
    getItems . parseTags . convertFuzzy Discard "CP1251" "UTF8"
```

And now became:

```
htmlToItems :: Text -> [Item]
htmlToItems =
    getItems . parseTags . fromLazyBS . convertFuzzy Discard "CP1251" "UTF8" . toLazyBS
    where
      toLazyBS t = fromChunks [encodeUtf8 t]
      fromLazyBS t = decodeUtf8 $ intercalate "" $ toChunks t
```

And yes, this function is not working because its wrong, if we supply `Text` to it, then we're confident this text is properly encoded and ready to use and converting it is stupid thing to do, but such a verbose conversion still has to take place somewhere outside `htmltoItems`.

Comment: Haskell folks please have a unified string :)

Comment: @Ankur: `Text` is becoming the de-facto textual implementation.  String is still around for legacy reasons and for simple things, but for serious textual manipulation you should be using Text.

Comment: @ivanm: if only all those legacy bytestring-based libraries would move convert!

Comment: @ivanm in reality it happens that Text not usable, i now use few libraries (Database.MongoDB, Text.Iconv) and none of them respect `Text`, and doing all that conversions by hand doesnt feel sane.

Comment: What is the signature of `parseTags`? Is it from `tagsoup` or some other HTML library?

Comment: yes, its TagSoup:
`parseTags :: StringLike str => str -> [Tag str]`

Comment: How and where do you originally get the Text? The reason you are running into problems is that you should never have to convert Text between different encodings. You should decode the Text data with the correct encoding in the first place and then just use `htmlToItems = getItems . parseTags`

Comment: Text From web with Network.Curl or from file, in both cases its charset differs, but not utf8

Comment: but i got your point and updated post, the problem with conversions still not gone.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

`ByteStrings` are mainly useful for binary data, but they are also an efficient way to process text if all you need is the ASCII character set. If you need to handle unicode strings, you need to use `Text`. However, I must emphasize that neither is a replacement for the other, and they are generally used for different things: while `Text` represents pure unicode, you still need to encode to and from a binary `ByteString` representation whenever you e.g. transport text via a socket or a file.

Here is a good article about the basics of unicode, which does a decent job of explaining the relation of unicode code-points (`Text`) and the encoded binary bytes (`ByteString`): [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

You can use the [Data.Text.Encoding](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/text/0.11.1.5/doc/html/Data-Text-Encoding.html) module to convert between the two datatypes, or [Data.Text.Lazy.Encoding](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/text/0.11.1.5/doc/html/Data-Text-Lazy-Encoding.html) if you are using the lazy variants (as you seem to be doing based on your error messages).

Comment: Here is hit the other side, because all my strings already Strict:
           Couldn't match expected type `Text
           against inferred type Data.Text.Lazy.Internal.Text`
So i found fromChunks for Text, ok, but final result yet ugly.

Comment: Please don't use bytestrings for "text" data, even if all you need is ASCII.  Use Text for textual data, and ByteString for packed data structures.  If we all agree on what types should represent **semantically**, we'll have a lot less confusion about which type to use, and ultimately, fewer conversions between types.

Comment: "you still need to encode to and from a binary ByteString representation whenever you e.g. transport text via a socket or a file."

The `text` package actually provides functions to work with files already.

Comment: Yes, the `Data.Text.IO` module has functions for working with files *but* they are almost never what you want. They internally decode `Text` from `ByteString` using the default character set of your system locale. If the file happens to have some other encoding, it will result in a run-time error or garbage text. Doing encoding and decoding explicitly is almost always the correct option.

Answer (score 26):

You definitely want to be using Data.Text for textual data.

`encodeUtf8` is the way to go.  This error:

> Couldn't match expected type Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal.ByteString
>   against inferred type Data.ByteString.Internal.ByteString

means that you're supplying a *strict* bytestring to code which expects a *lazy* bytestring.  Conversion is easy with the `fromChunks` function:

```
Data.ByteString.Lazy.fromChunks :: [Data.ByteString.Internal.ByteString] -> ByteString
```

so all you need to do is add the function `fromChunks [myStrictByteString]` wherever the lazy bytestring is expected.

Conversion the other way can be accomplished with the dual function `toChunks`, which takes a lazy bytestring and gives a list of strict chunks.

You may want to ask the maintainers of some packages if they'd be able to provide a text interface instead of, or in addition to, a bytestring interface.

Answer (score 7):

Use a single function `cs` from the `Data.String.Conversions`.

It will allow you to convert between `String`, `ByteString` and `Text` (as well as `ByteString.Lazy` and `Text.Lazy`), depending on the input and the expected types.

You still have to call it, but no longer to worry about the respective types.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27426772/1274978) for usage example.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, I found these two helper functions to be quite useful:

```hs
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as BS
import qualified Data.Text             as T

-- | Text to ByteString
tbs :: T.Text -> BS.ByteString
tbs = BS.pack . T.unpack

-- | ByteString to Text
bst :: BS.ByteString -> T.Text
bst = T.pack . BS.unpack
```

Example:

```hs
foo :: [BS.ByteString]
foo = ["hello", "world"]

bar :: [T.Text]
bar = bst <$> foo

baz :: [BS.ByteString]
baz = tbs <$> bar
```