# Converting Data.Text to Int in Haskell

Tags: string, haskell, type-conversion

In [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7357775/96233), one of the comments says, "`[Data.]Text` is becoming the de-facto textual implementation. `String` is still around for legacy reasons and for simple things, but for serious textual manipulation you should be using `Text`."

What is the easiest way to convert a `Data.Text` to an `Int`? `read` will not work because the `read` function always takes a `String`.

The best that I can come up with is:

```
let fortyTwo = Data.Text.pack "42"
read $ Data.Text.unpack fortyTwo :: Int
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: I'm not convinced that packing "42" as Text and then reading is is genuinely faster than reading it directly! If you have to examine the input character-by-character anyway, String isn't really slowing you down.

Comment: The `let fortyTwo = Data.Text.pack "42"` was just to set up an example for ghci. My real string comes from a regular expression match.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Looking at [the `text` package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text), I see a module called [`Data.Text.Read`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/text/0.11.2.3/doc/html/Data-Text-Read.html). It seems to work:

```
λ> decimal (T.pack "99 bottles")
Right (99," bottles")
λ> decimal (T.pack "a digit")
Left "input does not start with a digit"
```

Comment: I'm not sure that will be shorter (or better), since I will still have to deal with the `Either`. That might be a reasonable replacement for `reads`.

Comment: Well, you have to deal with that anyway, for most uses of `read`. `read` will crash your program if it sees a malformed string, which is pretty bad (it would probably be better if its type was `Read a => a -> Maybe String`). If you're sure you want to crash your program, you can always define `foo f = fst . either error id . f`, and then use `foo decimal` instead of `decimal`.

Comment: In my case, I **know** the string is a number; it comes from a regular expression match (`"\d{2}"`).

Comment: What is at mean «**know** the string is a number»? If you know that something is a number, that it is a number. These types are not equal, that why not every `String` could be converted to `Int`. Maybe something like `either (const 0) fst` will be useful, which is kinda `fromMaybe 0`.

Comment: Then feel free to do what I said. Crashing your program shouldn't be the default. :-) An alternative might be to combine the regular expression match and the reading into one function that returns `Either`/`Maybe`. It depends on what your code is like.

Comment: Please don't misunderstand. I **like** your answer.

Answer (score 15):

In other words, you want a parser that can consume `Text`.  There are many parsers on hackage that can consume Text, I suggest you try [attoparsec](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/attoparsec/0.10.3.0/doc/html/Data-Attoparsec-Text.html).

```
import Data.Attoparsec.Text
parseInt = parseOnly (signed decimal)
```