# Automatic conversion between String and Data.Text in haskell

Tags: string, haskell, type-conversion

As Nikita Volkov mentioned in his question [Data.Text vs String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19608745/data-text-vs-string) I also wondered why I have to deal with the different String implementations `type String = [Char]` and `Data.Text` in haskell. In my code I use the `pack` and `unpack` functions really often.

*My question:* Is there a way to have an automatic conversion between both string types so that I can avoid writing `pack` and `unpack` so often?

In other programming languages like Python or JavaScript there is for example an automatic conversion between integers and floats if it is needed. Can I reach something like this also in haskell? I know, that the mentioned languages are weakly typed, but I heard that C++ has a similar feature.

*Note:* I already know the language extension `{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}`. But as I understand this language extensions just applies to strings defined as `"..."`. I want to have an automatic conversion for strings which I got from other functions or I have as arguments in function definitions.

*Extended question:* [Haskell. Text or Bytestring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7357775/haskell-text-or-bytestring) covers also the difference between `Data.Text` and `Data.ByteString`. Is there a way to have an automatic conversion between the three strings `String`, `Data.Text` and `Data.ByteString`?

Comment: There is no such thing and cannot be, if you want type inference.

Comment: AFAIK the answer to this is no, Haskell does not automatically convert between types.  You can get automatic conversion only for literals, because string literals have type `AsString a => a` just like number literals have type `Num a => a`, but you don't get automatic conversions on runtime values.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

No.

Haskell doesn't have implicit coercions for technical, philosophical, and almost religious reasons.

As a comment, converting between these representations *isn't* free and most people don't like the idea that you have hidden and potentially expensive computations lurking around. Additionally, with strings as lazy lists, coercing them to a `Text` value might not terminate.

We can convert literals to `Text`s automatically with `OverloadedString`s by desugaring a string literal `"foo"` to `fromString "foo"` and `fromString` for `Text` just calls `pack`.

The question might be to ask why you're coercing so much? Is there some why do you need to `unpack` `Text` values so often? If you constantly changing them to strings it defeats the purpose a bit.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and explanation. I just asked because I wonder if I can omit often used ``pack`` and ``ùnpack`` (I need Data.Text because it is more memory efficient but I use many packages using Strings)

Comment: If you're having to `unpack` to pass data to other packages, you're more or less losing most of the advantages of `Text`.

Comment: As an aside, I'd love to know what the 'almost religious' reasons are.

Answer (score 34):

**Almost Yes: `Data.String.Conversions`**

Haskell libraries make use of different types, so there are many situations in which there is no choice but to heavily use conversion, distasteful as it is  - rewriting libraries doesn't count as a real choice.

I see two concrete problems, either of which being potentially a significant problem for Haskell adoption :

- coding ends up requiring specific implementation knowledge of the libraries you want to use.This is a big issue for a *high-level* language
- performance on simple tasks is bad - which is a [big issue](http://honza.ca/2012/10/haskell-strings) for a *generalist* language.

**Abstracting from the specific types**

In my experience, the first problem is the time spent guessing the package name holding the right function for plumbing between libraries that basically operate on the same data.

To *that* problem there is a really handy solution : the `Data.String.Conversions` [package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/string-conversions-0.2.1/docs/Data-String-Conversions.html), provided you are comfortable with UTF-8 as your default encoding.

This package provides a single `cs` conversion function between a number of different types.

- `String`
- `Data.ByteString.ByteString`
- `Data.ByteString.Lazy.ByteString`
- `Data.Text.Text`
- `Data.Text.Lazy.Text`

So you just `import Data.String.Conversions`, and use `cs` which will infer the right version of the conversion function according to input and output types.

Example:

```
import Data.Aeson              (decode)
import Data.Text               (Text)
import Data.ByteString.Lazy    (ByteString)
import Data.String.Conversions (cs)

decodeTextStoredJson' :: T.Text -> MyStructure
decodeTextStoredJson' x = decode (cs x) :: Maybe MyStructure
```

NB : In GHCi you generally do not have a context that gives the target type so you direct the conversion by explicitly stating the type of the result, like for `read`

```
let z = cs x :: ByteString
```

**Performance and the cry for a "true" solution**

I am not aware of any true solution as of yet - but we can already guess the direction

- it is legitimate to require conversion because the data does not change ;
- best performance is achieved by *not* converting data from one type to another for administrative purposes ;
- coercion is evil - coercitive, even.

So the direction must be to make these types not different, i.e. to reconcile them under (or over) an archtype from which they would all derive, allowing composition of functions using different derivations, without the need to convert.

Nota : I absolutely cannot evaluate the feasability / potential drawbacks of this idea. There may be some very sound stoppers.

Comment: Can you illustrate a ghci application of cs?
Prelude Data.String.Conversions Data.String.Conversions> cs "stuff"

<interactive>:10:1: error:
    • Non type-variable argument
        in the constraint: ConvertibleStrings [Char] b
      (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
    • When checking the inferred type
        it :: forall b. ConvertibleStrings [Char] b => b