# Most elegant way to do string conversion in Haskell

Tags: string, haskell, text, type-conversion

See this related SO question: [Automatic conversion between String and Data.Text in haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22641847/automatic-conversion-between-string-and-data-text-in-haskell)

Given a string of type `Text`, I want to produce a lazy bytestring.

This works, but I wondered whether it's optimal, given the fact that both `Text` and the lazy bytestring have the property of being "string-like" and I still use the not-generic `unpack`:

```
import qualified   Data.ByteString.Lazy (ByteString)
import             Data.Text            (Text, unpack)
import             Data.String          (fromString)
import             Data.Text            (unpack)

convert :: IsString str => Text -> str
convert = fromString . unpack
```

I found the package [string-conversions](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/string-conversions-0.4/docs/Data-String-Conversions.html) that offers the polymorphic function

```
 convertString :: a -> b
```

as part of the `ConvertibleStrings` typeclass.

While it works fine, I am suspicious: Why would I need an extra package for that? Couldn't there be already a typeclass like `IsString` that offers a `toString` method and in combination a universal convert function `fromString . toString`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Ok, while I was editing my question, a possible answer dawned to me]

On the [hackage-page of string-conversions](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/string-conversions-0.4/docs/Data-String-Conversions.html) it says:

> Assumes UTF-8 encoding for both types of ByteStrings.

So there are assumptions that go along with conversions and a universal conversion of string-like types might not be desirable.
Also performance probably depends on the input and output types and a universal conversion would pretend that it's all the same.

So my take on best practice is now this, being explicit rather than polymorphic:

```
import           Data.ByteString.Lazy (ByteString)
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as ByteString
import qualified Data.Text.Encoding   as Text

convert :: Text -> ByteString
convert = ByteString.fromStrict . Text.encodeUtf8
```